# Front page displays to a static page makes two homepage for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, menu

I am new to wordpress. I wanted to change my homepage to a static page, so I created a static page named `home`, then in Reading settings I set front page displays to `Home`. Now though clicking home button shows the contents of the page I have created, it shows two `home` buttons in my menubar. It looks very odd. How can I make it better.[image: my menu looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the menu via `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menu`.
Create a new menu and add the pages you need to show in menu.
Select the appropriate menu in center-left panel.

Try this way.